# How to convert str to hex via python

Tags: python

I want to convert string to a hex (decimal),
for example `abc` to `616263` and so on.
How do I do that?

I have tried:

```
x= input("Enter string")
x = int(x)
hex(x)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Well, yeah, you're not assigning the results of `hex` to anything.

Comment: What is "a hex (decimal)"? What does "abc" have to do with 616263?

Comment: @khelwood As I can think, It's ASCII in Hexadecimal value of `abc`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like:

```
x.encode("hex")
```

Comment: having issue :/ LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Comment: you could try to 
`from codecs import encode, decode
 encode(x, "hex")`